# Can't get built-in inverse trig autovectorization to work (gcc or clang)

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, vectorization, simd

I've been trying to get some `std::atan2` code to auto vectorize.  I've been able to get it to the point where GCC doesn't complain about `asin`, but it doesn't seem to be able to handle `atan2` (nor `atan` for that matter).

Here is a [link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAGYADKS3oAMnlqYAcsYBGmYlwBspAA6oFQnVaPUMTcyt/QLU6e0cXI3dPTh8lFRjaBgJmYgJQ41NJAFZFZUxVYKycgjjnNw9vRWzc/PDipurahKTvAEpFVANiZA4AcnELAEEpMwdkQywAanEzHWQjZgIEFewJ6clZ2nmDJZW1hQJ0LCodvZm5hcxl1ZziZgBPW6m9tFoLzAAHr5iIsLugQCBAgAvTAAfQIi1eH1h7FEW2eABFFikVrJvlMAG6oPDoRYsVjIWEGAmwtAkfC0TaYBQQPaLdlkugXUGXCFIz6rKisVCbUj8lFaYBbW6SLyLKKwgGkNkc37csF84hvAU6IUighirXI1FS7ZmXay%2BUBWHvZVTDmcv4IjUgflnPWi8Um6XmqRyhVQu2TB0ut2C4Weo3vCVos0WuUEQFUoMh3muqPuiMGr2Sn3xxaJgGwgm9Ra0VCAka%2BAjiADseODHJmwOYwA2ZOEokWwtQvkWBPKRGIeBhEC0zFc7F6KvZNGIEBd0LhCLwmMWFlxi1XZ0RUZjps3cjkeGn9ZnDoLSYM4iK0jwN6xKyxoeytEkEADN7vD9IVoUiq/e8igxUsAHpFggSRFgAKkWABZWEAAUAElpzMBsLw5Qti0Ah811DQJaA/a1PlvICQMWcCEJQ3FzzrDE7lrDFRn6VgQFGIpRlIUxRgsLjUHYnQjxkUFBmGJ4Zk4LiCHYvjen6ABrcxuAAOkkABObhOCKAAOLxJE4ThZTMHShHY7guJ4vjSAE0YuIUEArBk3iWNIOBYBgKBPIgJA0CMXw8HYMgKAgPyAqClBO2AdSLCsKhAsTYgHIgVxZK41wHByd52Kk0g/KMLQCAAeVoVhspc0gsA2UR2DSyq8GIQc8AHByKsBcoDETOqHETNiKtYPBXDeYh3j0LAcuk4cjAm/oaHoJg2A4Hh%2BEEKKUGE%2BQBtcBzIH6XsMlagBaZBFkOoqqGYblDqoC6LkOjZ0UOgAlXxLoUQ6RDYd5AgUJ8e18Q6B1UEgR0weyygqDQx20VpTE4axtC6epkj8AIgjoWHBCidHaCRxIGnhtImroKoWn0ApBCJyHMmaGoHDqfGUYuapMcJ2m8Z6Th%2BgUMSRi4Vj2M47i6tsgE9MOrxuA7ERgEWdSVIsBWINwQgSGWA54cWPR/MCjx1bMLmtY26S0vk0gEEwZgsE8CBFJAIovBUlIvFrDSikkHSzC9/SfD6izSGm7gzBUooLG4IoYosMwI50sOzGFirbPsxzSGcuS3O8pBBgIXxOvISgwt1lHMHwIdBDmxhySW3gAHc3l8GazI4yyRfYyTFhrwgEEWMWvAlqX5hluWFYVk2XLNi2rYaW3SCUoOVM9sxJFrMPa2drwzFrXg/ZbxP2OTpzTYF0ZJC4wPOCdzeDlrHSdLXzhayKZarP4/fU9NjP4HcxAUFQHWgvzqFP%2B4UGjRUkKQeKrBErJVShVDKjIRoTTyn/Aq9ASplTqlVGWtUKr4EahUFqdV2rIE6mMayPVlB1S2sNUaGAxi5QIFNRuFcFq1WWgIcBa0JAyDkEIQaO0Z77WCEdE6p1zqXQRNdW6BB7qbG7tdfah0HA0EBuUe6eAFBKFJAo6sSjaAqKBuDdIwRNAw3JuEeGNgOYE1RtEYIrNbE42sUzCGGRSZ5HMXDUoxiSbs3pt0GxzMyZhC8UEum8Rkb8wGEMPmXMm5CxfjZdivd%2B6LGAMgE68soIQBVkOfWmttYgJBDMSQpYhI8JkGPOS/RJ7W0oHbTeCsLDLwMlvZpOll61ibv7aaDsVLcHUkUbgFh1LqUlhYTggyumJKTooFOadXLfx8iAbOucDQhULhFcBJdVYoxYVXLgtd66Nz6gk1u4wDhQU7uiFJks0kZOHqfd%2B48amWzqTPJS%2BkVKjNdjfYo6k16u3jjvBO1lZkOUPi8puTzek6QXvpWs%2BlDIew6dwPSoLX52WedU2eIAvBFBUivXSWlN631rGYSWTczC7zBW/BZZs%2BpPJmXSo%2BpABxJRMdwIAA%3D%3D) to the godbolt version. here is the source code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

constexpr std::size_t array_length = 16;

void calc_uv_coordinates(
    const std::array<float,array_length>& pos_x,
    const std::array<float,array_length>& pos_y,
    const std::array<float,array_length>& pos_z,
    std::array<float,array_length>& tex_u,
    std::array<float,array_length>& tex_v) noexcept{
    #pragma clang loop vectorize(enable)
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < array_length; ++i){
        tex_u[i] = std::atan2(pos_z[i], pos_x[i]) / (2 * M_PI);
        tex_v[i] = std::asin(pos_y[i]) / M_PI;
    }
}
```

Here are the compiler arguments:

clang 9.0: `-c -Ofast -ffast-math -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize`

gcc 9.2: `-c  -Ofast -ffast-math -fopt-info-vec-missed -fopt-info-vec`

Clang says:

```
In file included from <source>:2:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/cmath:145:12: remark: loop not vectorized: call instruction cannot be vectorized [-Rpass-analysis]

  { return __builtin_atan2f(__y, __x); }

           ^

<source>:15:5: warning: loop not vectorized: the optimizer was unable to perform the requested transformation; the transformation might be disabled or specified as part of an unsupported transformation ordering [-Wpass-failed=transform-warning]

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < array_length; ++i){

    ^

1 warning generated.

ASM generation compiler returned: 0

clang-9: warning: -Wl,-rpath,/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-9.0.0/lib: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

clang-9: warning: -Wl,-rpath,/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-9.0.0/lib32: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

clang-9: warning: -Wl,-rpath,/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-9.0.0/lib64: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

In file included from <source>:2:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../include/c++/9.2.0/cmath:145:12: remark: loop not vectorized: call instruction cannot be vectorized [-Rpass-analysis]

  { return __builtin_atan2f(__y, __x); }

           ^

<source>:15:5: warning: loop not vectorized: the optimizer was unable to perform the requested transformation; the transformation might be disabled or specified as part of an unsupported transformation ordering [-Wpass-failed=transform-warning]

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < array_length; ++i){

    ^

1 warning generated.

Execution build compiler returned: 0

Program returned: 1

Error: no suitable ./output.s executable found
```

GCC says:

```
<source>:15:30: missed: couldn't vectorize loop

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/cmath:145:28: missed: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: _15 = __builtin_atan2f (_2, _1);

ASM generation compiler returned: 0

<source>:15:30: missed: couldn't vectorize loop

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/cmath:145:28: missed: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: _15 = __builtin_atan2f (_2, _1);

Execution build compiler returned: 0

Program returned: 1

Error: no suitable ./output.s executable found
```

I'm not sure I understand what `relevant stmt not supported: _15 = __builtin_atan2f (_2, _1);` is saying, I believe it is saying that GCC has not put in the manual effort to auto vectorize the built in.  It appears that GCC only auto vectorizes trig with built-in assembly instructions, but I don't understand why that forces atan2f off the table for vectorization, or why that makes it any different than an arbitrary arithmetic function.

Other libraries have [SIMD `atan` and `atan2`](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xsimd/blob/master/include/xsimd/math/xsimd_invtrigo.hpp), so it isn't like this function is impossible to vectorize.  In principle this should just be each part of `atan2` being vectorized along all elements.

Comment: Modern GCC usually comes with glibc's libmvec; that would be the library to check for a vectorized atan2f being available for gcc to use in the first place.